# How can I isolate the css classes of my embeddable Web component

Tags: css, web, frontend

I have written an embeddable Web component for data visualization. There are of course associated css classes in addition to the js and html. I need to isolate the css classes so they do not override and/or clobber css class names of the larger Web app context it gets embedded in.

What is the best practice for achieving this?

Comment: You can create .css files with definations (starting with . and #) in it and embed the specific .css file in each web page and yes you have to make sure that definations should be unique.

Comment: So there's no concept of namespaces or something similar?

Comment: No as far as I know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>A possible way to fix this problem is to use [scoped CSS](https://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/). I don't prefer the solution and only use it when nothing else is possible.</strike>

I just found out that scoping is not supported, at least not all browsers support it, [only Firefox does](http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped)

Another solution would be to use a prefix for all your CSS classes and id's, but this could take a lot of time if your files are large.

By the way, if embedding means in an iframe, there is no problem, because it does not apply the css of the site imbedded in.

Comment: Another possible solution would be to insert a container div into the template of the component and require all CSS classes to be a child of the class or id you assign to the container div.

Comment: @w3re I never considered that option. Maybe I can use it in the future as I am a frontend developer myself :)